# php - mysqli_stmnt::get_result equivalent

Tags: php, mysqli, phplint

I am developing an internet site, using php 5.3, and mysql for database.

When using the database, after lines such as:

...

```
  $stmnt = $mysqli->prepare("Select ID from users where loginid = ?");
    $stmnt->bind_param('i', $x);
    $stmnt->execute();
    $result = $stmnt->get_result();
```

is there any equivalent command for : `$stmnt->get_result();`

This is because I am using phplint (http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line.html) and I get a compilation error : ERROR: the method mysqli_stmt::get_result() does not exist

Some workarround leads to conclusion that some server doesn't support $stmnt->get_result() (otherwise, I don't know why the code cannot be compiled).

Is there any equivalent to `$stmnt->get_result()`?

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Possibly

```
$stmt->fetch();
```

or

```
$result = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: The query could be i.e : select * from logins where id > 10
and returns 100 rows, so result->num_rows can return 100.
What do you mean about stmnt->fetch(); - I put it instead result = $stmnt->get_result(), but result still has 0 ros ($result->num_rows),
also $result = $result->fetch_assoc() is not valid command.